# Replacing a string if it contains alphabet from an array in js

Tags: javascript

I have an array like `['adsd','ssd2','3244']`. I want to replace a string if it contains any alphabet with '----'. So, the above array should be like `['----','----','3244']`. How can I do that? Can I so it with regular expression?

Comment: "*Can I [do] it with regular expression?*" - yes, yes you can. But what have you tried, where did you get stuck? What help did you expect? Should the `-` strings be the same length of the array elements you're replacing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yourArray.map(str => /[a-z]/i.test(str) ? '----' : str)
```

Comment: What exactly is the OP supposed to learn from this unexplained code? How are they supposed to learn from this unexplained code?

Comment: @DavidThomas, it's simple enough that just looking at it and wondering how it works someone can learn from it by example. It hardly needs to be explained step-by-step to be a learning experience.

Comment: This won't work in any version of IE, including the latest one, because IE doesn't support arrow functions.

Comment: Read the question, does it seem the OP is likely to understand your answer? It is, however, a subjective opinion. And without an explanatory edit and update I stand by mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
['adsd','ssd2','3244'].map(function(item) {
    return /[a-z]/i.test(item) ? '----' : item;
});
```

Edit: a bit of explanation about what's happening here.

`map()` applies a function that transforms every element of the array. [More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

`/[a-z]/i` is a regex that matches every character in the alphabet. The `i` makes it case-insensitive, so it matches `a` and also `A`.

`test` checks whether a given string matches the regex. [More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

`? '----' : item` uses a `ternary operator` to return either `----` or the original string, depending on whether the string has any alphabetic character. [More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Comment: What exactly is the OP supposed to learn from this unexplained code? How are they supposed to learn from this unexplained code?